# Repeating OpenGL-es texture bound to hills in cocos2d 3.2

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

ORIGINAL ARTICLE

I am in the process of trying to implement raywenderlich's tutorial on generating hills with repeating striped coordinates using cocos2d, This article was written for Cocos2D, and as I am trying to port it to Cocos2Dx 3.2 This means updating it for openGl-es 2. So far everything has worked perfectly, However I am having problems with getting the texture of the hill to repeat properly and also after some repeatation the texture start degrade ... 
 please help me to get texture properly.......
Here is my code:

```
#define Point_FROM_B2VEC(v) Point((v.x*PTM_RATIO),(v.y*PTM_RATIO))
        #define B2VEC_FROM_Point(v) b2Vec2(v.x/PTM_RATIO,v.y/PTM_RATIO)
    #define PTM_RATIO       32
    #define MAX_HILL_POINTS 15
    #define MAX_SEGMENTS    MAX_HILL_POINTS*10
    #define MAX_COORDINATES 600

        Point hillTopVertices[MAX_COORDINATES],hillBottomVertices[MAX_COORDINATES];
            Point hillTopTexCoords[MAX_COORDINATES];
     Point hillBottomTexCoords[MAX_COORDINATES];

            GLuint         terraintopTexId, terrainBottomTexId;
     float         terrainTopTexSize,  terrainBottomTexSize;
```

Sending the hills the texture:

```
         texture = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage("surface.png");

            terraintopTexId = texture->getName();
            terrainTopTexSize = texture->getPixelsWide()/2;

    //terrain top texture
        texture1 = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage("old_stone_wall_textures_v3_3000x2000_1.jpg");


        terrainBottomTexId = texture1->getName();
        terrainBottomTexSize = texture1->getPixelsWide()/2;



void Terrain::generateCoordinates()
{
    int nTopVertCount = 0;
     int nTopVertCount1 = 0;

    //get the hill vertex and texcoordinates
    for(short i = 0; i < MAX_SEGMENTS; ++i)
    {
        Point point1 = Point_FROM_B2VEC(vertices[i]);
        Point point2 = Point_FROM_B2VEC(vertices[i+1]);






        CCLOG("%f",terrainBottomTexSize);

        hillTopVertices[nTopVertCount1]      = Point(point1.x, point1.y+16);
        hillTopTexCoords[nTopVertCount1++]   = Point(point1.x/terrainTopTexSize, 1);
        hillTopVertices[nTopVertCount1]      = Point(point2.x, point2.y+16);
        hillTopTexCoords[nTopVertCount1++]   = Point(point2.x/terrainTopTexSize, 1);

        hillTopVertices[nTopVertCount1]      = Point(point1.x, point1.y-16);
        hillTopTexCoords[nTopVertCount1++]   = Point(point1.x/terrainTopTexSize, 0);
        hillTopVertices[nTopVertCount1]      = Point(point2.x, point2.y-16);
        hillTopTexCoords[nTopVertCount1++]   = Point(point2.x/terrainTopTexSize, 0);

    }

        for(short i = 0; i < MAX_SEGMENTS; ++i)
        {
            Point point1 = Point_FROM_B2VEC(vertices[i]);
            Point point2 = Point_FROM_B2VEC(vertices[i+1]);

        hillBottomVertices[nTopVertCount]      = Point(point1.x, point1.y-terrainBottomTexSize+1);
        hillBottomTexCoords[nTopVertCount++]   = Point(point1.x/terrainBottomTexSize, 1);
        hillBottomVertices[nTopVertCount]      = Point(point2.x, point2.y-terrainBottomTexSize+1);
        hillBottomTexCoords[nTopVertCount++]   = Point(point2.x/terrainBottomTexSize, 1);

        hillBottomVertices[nTopVertCount]      = Point(point1.x, point1.y+2);
        hillBottomTexCoords[nTopVertCount++]   = Point(point1.x/terrainBottomTexSize, 0);
        hillBottomVertices[nTopVertCount]      = Point(point2.x, point2.y+2);
        hillBottomTexCoords[nTopVertCount++]   = Point(point2.x/terrainBottomTexSize, 0);
        }
        //energy adding

        //CCLOG("hillsegment---%d,pointx---%f,pointy---%f,offset--%f",i,point1.x,point1.y,offsetX);









}
void Terrain::draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
{


    Node::draw(renderer, transform, flags);

    _renderCmds[0].init(0.0f);
    _renderCmds[0].func = CC_CALLBACK_0(Terrain::onDraw, this, transform);
    renderer->addCommand(&_renderCmds[0]);



}
void Terrain::onDraw(const Mat4 &transform) {



    auto glProgram = getGLProgram();
    glProgram->use();
    glProgram->setUniformsForBuiltins(transform);

    GL::bindTexture2D( terrainBottomTexId );
    GL::enableVertexAttribs( GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POS_COLOR_TEX );

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, hillBottomVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, hillBottomTexCoords);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)MAX_COORDINATES);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    GL::bindTexture2D(terraintopTexId );
    GL::enableVertexAttribs( GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POS_COLOR_TEX );

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, hillTopVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, hillTopTexCoords);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)MAX_COORDINATES);


    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

}
```

Comment: If the quality degrades after some repetitions, this sounds like a precision issue. What float precision are you specifying in your shader?

Comment: #define MAX_HILL_POINTS 15
#define MAX_SEGMENTS    MAX_HILL_POINTS*10
#define MAX_COORDINATES 600
  b2Vec2          vertices[MAX_SEGMENTS];
and more require tell me.
  
    CCPoint         hillTopVertices[MAX_COORDINATES], hillBottomVertices[MAX_COORDINATES];
 CCPoint         hillTopTexCoords[MAX_COORDINATES], hillBottomTexCoords[MAX_COORDINATES];